# How to plot r squared for regression model for multiple group in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
o<-read.csv("old.csv')

Callosal_FA CST_FA  SLF_FA  Area_SMA_A
0.556566554 0.539971971 0.482016736 -0.007984
0.586793895 0.554954237 0.487595985 0.05567
0.613107046 0.597039029 0.467378312 0.136
0.59241945  0.58101919  0.460784717 0.03253
0.586344082 0.555524562 0.479480255 -0.01629
0.607088378 0.56048251  0.478998182 0.07981
0.595145661 0.571902322 0.461452732 0.07882
0.591501695 0.581156582 0.51408736  0.1143
0.587255765 0.566562088 0.462376015 0.1717
0.583943048 0.571209263 0.46400787  -0.01861
0.603512157 0.587332337 0.477376739 0.05672
0.582126533 0.565946603 0.459743433 0.002831
0.570966197 0.556258709 0.470341615 -0.003823
0.570307147 0.542675924 0.504833121 0.01764
0.579498276 0.569837284 0.475364742 -0.000387
0.570543729 0.542095809 0.468923119 0.117
0.613672747 0.572339549 0.486481493 0.1264
0.570649037 0.554125163 0.522845609 0.04696
0.580601176 0.558799894 0.504017998 0.1056
0.576166024 0.542110191 0.476548484 0.05783
0.579598762 0.546776236 0.491528835 0.08022
0.604775228 0.576144869 0.506060596 0.1515
0.555354582 0.556518053 0.492985322 -0.01114
0.580857907 0.556575944 0.484096309 0.03578
```

I wanted to plot the regression model result (r squared) for multiple group. 
I have tried this one and managed to do for one group.

```
 y <- lm(o$Area_SMA_A ~ o$CST_FA + o$SLF_FA + o$Callosal_FA)
```

then by using the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(y$model, aes_string(x = names(y$model)[2], y = names(y$model)[1])) + 
     geom_point() + 
     stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "lightblue") + 
     labs(title = paste("Adj R2 = ",signif(summary(y)$adj.r.squared, 5), 
                        "Intercept =",signif(y$coef[[1]],5 ), 
                        " Slope =",signif(y$coef[[2]], 5), 
                        " P =",signif(summary(y)$coef[2,4], 5)))
```

I produced this image, which what I wanted.

[image]

For I have three groups, I want to add another regression model for the two groups into this plot. Is there a way to do it please? Thank you.

```
m <- read.csv("middle.csv')

Callosal_FA CST_FA  SLF_FA  Area_SMA_A
0.599350895 0.59082334  0.518316923 0.04286
0.591540991 0.585592011 0.517415822 0.1291
0.62120411  0.613751115 0.456966929 0.05915
0.59344635  0.571179365 0.500941682 0.01122
0.621645795 0.599144316 0.487736421 0.0471
0.611521291 0.596407776 0.508636999 -0.08177
0.561589532 0.549150165 0.509993364 -0.002053
0.608089072 0.581477369 0.496346462 0.1157
0.583942196 0.576979247 0.505747697 0.01913
0.614675486 0.584447311 0.513085904 0.006673
0.599312499 0.585156336 0.475447955 0.05582
0.591977354 0.578031977 0.505042846 0.08293
0.602347244 0.582916321 0.504538196 -0.07645
0.628674145 0.595462642 0.469785878 0.04787
0.595963981 0.547983665 0.497874226 0.1132
0.604934306 0.586583356 0.502788492 0.08803
0.599656344 0.580235613 0.471793292 0.0118
0.587288357 0.559298093 0.535857414 0.06225
0.586031623 0.582565008 0.475876222 0.282
0.58277546  0.555852007 0.497386116 0.05266

y <- read.csv("young.csv')

Callosal_FA CST_FA  SLF_FA  Area_SMA_A
0.641939581 0.610050256 0.497039292 -0.05461
0.600969207 0.581011925 0.486918544 0.03801
0.597728695 0.569094851 0.522076721 0.08515
0.605851215 0.575788238 0.522207993 0.001711
0.615141198 0.586422768 0.49536629  0.08908
0.664600517 0.636086957 0.50723616  0.04712
0.617076761 0.577625164 0.50950881  0.02169
0.612482041 0.569112478 0.512551218 0.04043
0.627284885 0.597122461 0.541768958 0.003275
0.627408656 0.607896037 0.505038914 0.06681
0.609205487 0.577178474 0.508818934 -0.04759
0.606824376 0.593485569 0.530833127 0.05503
0.608929339 0.583816742 0.506553103 0.08804
0.623125338 0.599054187 0.518118823 0.04499
0.606161965 0.578010045 0.491883074 0.1487
0.605391626 0.585302201 0.488368677 0.1316
0.640007128 0.599344654 0.503622583 0.1909
0.598483618 0.588507596 0.508622188 0.2013
0.625079582 0.597286968 0.510829857 0.09116
0.620938861 0.577980188 0.52410613  0.02284
0.615765316 0.577922653 0.542867003 0.08179
0.606476852 0.571277288 0.486362068 0.2072
0.607761045 0.585516175 0.509739355 0.075
0.633673687 0.615854958 0.470963903 0.02209
0.641553411 0.621000635 0.492999164 0.101
0.588310547 0.57312727  0.490874808 0.07214
0.588535558 0.571499503 -0.08068    -0.03153
```

Comment: You can generally omit any data in the call to `ggplot` and add the data to the specific `geoms`, like `ggplot() + geom_point(y$model, aes(...) + geom_point(z$model, aes(...)` and so on. This way you can use multiple data sources (models in your case) within one plot. You can also use `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()` in `ggplot2` to create facetted plots, or try the package `gridExtra`.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of data?

Comment: @LAP Thank you. Sure. I can post some of the data.

Comment: @Tobia You can use `dput(head(YourDataset,20))` to make a dataset with 20 rows

Comment: @LAP I don't know how to add data from csv files. I use the java script option.

Comment: Here's an approach, though calculating the R^2 values beforehand is cleaner. `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, color = factor(cyl))) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
    scale_color_discrete(quote(Cylinders / R^2), labels = function(cyls) lapply(cyls, function(cl){paste(cl, "/", round(summary(lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars, subset = mtcars$cyl == cl))$adj.r.squared, 2))}))` This puts the values in the legend. If you facet, you could also put them in the strip labels.